# Nested div element jumping down

Tags: html, css

I'm having problem with a nested div element (#navbar) that is supposed to stay in place when you resize the browser window but it jumps down. Here is the HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Uppgift 18</title>

<style>
    body{
        background-color: #ffffff;
        width: 100%;
        padding-left: 2%;
    }
    #container{
        left: 25%;
        width: 80%;
        background-color: dodgerblue;
        padding-bottom: 25px;
    }
    #header{
        background-color: orangered;
        height: 60px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    #header h1{
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    #navbar{
        background-color: dodgerblue;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 340px;
        width: 22%;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
    #navbar ul li{
        list-style: none;
    }
    #content{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        word-break: break-all;
        background-color: white;
        height: 340px;
    }
    #content2{
        padding-left: 10px;
        width: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
        word-break: break-all;
        float: left;
    }
    #content2 h3{
        color: orangered;
    }
    #nyheter{
        padding: 15px;
        background-color: skyblue;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 25%;
        height: 310px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <h1><b>Webbplatsens namn</b></h1>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="content2">
            <h3>Om webbplatsens namn</h3>
            <p>
                Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text
                Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text
                Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text
                Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text
                Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text
                Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text
            </p>
            <p>
                Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text
                Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text
                Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text
                Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text
                Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text
                Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="nyheter">
            <h3><b>Nyheter</b></h3>
            Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text
            Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text
            Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text
            Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text
            Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text
            Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText tex
        </div>
        <div id="navbar">
            <h3><b>Avsnitt</b></h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Hem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Om</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tjänster</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Medarbetare</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfölj</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Kontakta oss</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <b style="float: right; text-align: center; color: #ffffff;">Copyright&nbsp;&copy;&nbsp;Webbplatsen 2014</b>
</div>
```

I've recently started with html/css so my code does probably not have the best structure.

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle

Comment: Oh boy, [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cZMZj/).  I would help you out what I have no idea what this is supposed to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's jumping down for a number of reasons.

1) You're not using `box-sizing: border-box` which would make your use of paddings and margins much easier, and more intuitive. Currently, your padding goes outside your divs which is adding to their actual size. By adding to their actual size, the `#navbar` is too large to sit to the right of your `#nyheter`.

2) You're not using positioning correctly. On your container, use `margin: 0 auto` to center it on the page.

3) You're using inline-block to try and get your elements to line up next to each other (and mixing floats in there as well). Inline-block creates white space between elements and will pop your elements down when this margin takes up enough space to overflow your containing div. Instead, at least in this case, use `float: left` on all of the children of `#content` and then a clearfix hack on `#content` so that it will retain it's height.

4) You don't need to put heights on `content2`, `nyheter` and `navbar`.

5) Lastly, use `clear:both` on your copyright, I added a div for you in my fiddle, to get it to sit below the content

Here's a fiddle to show you what it should look like when you fix everything: http://jsfiddle.net/kyleshevlin/9yj3V/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you completely without a visual. The comments above are asking you to set up a jsfiddle.net demo and paste the link so we can see your site code's layout in full.

Off the cuff, I'd try taking the navbar out of the #content div and make it only a child of #container. Try setting a pixel limit to your width rather than a percentage. Maybe put a width of 1000px for your container and set your #navbar to 220p (22% of it).

```
   #navbar{
       background-color: dodgerblue;
       display: inline-block;
       height: 340px;
       width: 220px;
       margin-left: 0px;
       margin-top: 0px;
   }
```